# Preg matching and counting the resulting match in a short string

Tags: php, text, count, preg-match

I already have a function that counts the number of items in a string ($paragraph) and tells me how many characters the result is, ie tsp and tbsp present is 7, I can use this to work out the percentage of that string is.

I need to reinforce this with preg_match because 10tsp should count as 5.

```
$characters = strlen($paragraph);
$items = array("tsp", "tbsp", "tbs");
    $count = 0;

        foreach($items as $item) {

            //Count the number of times the formatting is in the paragraph
            $countitems = substr_count($paragraph, $item);
            $countlength= (strlen($item)*$countitems);

            $count = $count+$countlength;
        }

    $overallpercent = ((100/$characters)*$count);
```

I know it would be something like `preg_match('#[d]+[item]#', $paragraph)` right?

**EDIT** sorry for the curve ball but there might be a space inbetween the number and the $item, can one preg_match catch both instances?

Comment: Not quite sure what you need to parse.... "tsptbsptbs..." or "5tbs3tsp.."? Can you give a couple of examples and expected outputs?

Comment: '10tsp' >> 5 || '1tsp' >> 4 || '1 tsp' >> 5 || '1 tsp and 2tbsp' >> 10 || Does that make sense? just character counting the matches of things in the array but also including numbers before it (with/without a space)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me what you are trying to do with the regex, but if you are just trying to match for a particular number-measurement combination, this might help:

```
$count = preg_match_all('/\d+\s*(tbsp|tsp|tbs)/', $paragraph);
```

This will return the number of times a number-measurement combination occurs in `$paragraph`.

**EDIT** switched to use `preg_match_all` to count all occurrences.

Example for counting the number of matched characters:

```
$paragraph = "5tbsp and 10 tsp";

$charcnt = 0;
$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all('/\d+\s*(tbsp|tsp|tbs)/', $paragraph, $matches) > 0) {
  foreach ($matches[0] as $match) { $charcnt += strlen($match); }
}

printf("total number of characters: %d\n", $charcnt);
```

Output from executing the above:

> total number of characters: 11

Comment: so how would i work out how many characters have been matched in your preg? ie     '5tsp and 10 tsp' //should be 10. does that make sense?

Comment: I added sample code for counting the number of characters in the matches from the regex.  Note that the regex only has a few measurement types...  You might need to add more suitable for your application.  Also, if the list becomes very long, you might want to choose a different approach, as you will start to notice performance problems with a large regex.

Comment: man oh man youve really gone and done it!! mate you've helped me out like you wouldnt even believe! Seriously I gotta send you a christmas present for this!

Comment: Glad it was helpful...  I'll be interested to see how it pops up on your site.  I've already sent it to my wife, so we'll be watching ;)