# Using php to count the number of uppercase letters in a string

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP, I need to determine if a string contains "more than one" uppercase letter.

The sentence above contains 4 uppercase letters: PHP and I

The count of how many uppercase letters is what I need. In the above sentence, that count would be 4.

I tried the preg_match_all below, but it only lets me know if any uppercase letters were found, even if the result is only one, or any number of occurrences.

```
if ( preg_match_all("/[A-Z]/", $string) === 0 )
{
     do something
}
```

Comment: you can do it like `if ( preg_match_all("/[A-Z]/", $string, $matches) > 1 )`. [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) returns the number of full pattern matches. Note: Without the third parameter a warning is generated.

Comment: bansi's comment above is the best solution, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823004/ (*which I did upvote*) and modified:

```
$string = "Peter wenT To the MarkeT";

$charcnt = 0;
$matches = array();
if (preg_match_all("/[A-Z]/", $string, $matches) > 0) {
  foreach ($matches[0] as $match) { $charcnt += strlen($match); }
}

printf("Total number of uppercase letters found: %d\n", $charcnt);

   echo "<br>from the string: $string: ";

foreach($matches[0] as $var){
   echo "<b>" . $var . "</b>";
}
```

Will output:

Total number of uppercase letters found: 5
from the string: Peter wenT To the MarkeT: **PTTMT**

Comment: This works great. $matches In my earlier attempts, I thought $matches was returning a count of how many matches, but have since discovered it returns a multidimensional array. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match('/[A-Z].*[A-Z]/', $string)){
  echo "there's more than 1 uppercase letter!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
if(strlen(preg_replace('![^A-Z]+!', '', $string)) > 1){
    echo "more than one upper case letter";
}
```